# ECS Instances cannot be Drained?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

In my AWS account I can see around 8 ECS instances are running since several months and those cannot be drained, therefor it incurs more cost to my AWS account.

[image]

Even when I try to drain it shows the following error,

[image: error]

Even when I try to check them from EC2 console, those are not available. Therefor I have no idea how to delete them before incur more cost.

Can anyone help me how to drain all those old ECS instances ?

Thanks.

Comment: for time being to save the cost until you are not able to drain, you can stop the instance so it will show agent connect to false and you will not paying more. Once you get to know the issue with draining you can drain them

Answer (score 0):

You can always open up a support ticket. If you're not paying for support open a billing issue and explain that these are costing you money and that you get an error when trying to remove them.

Comment: let me try that